# Box added after appendix name and number

Tags: appendix

I am writing my thesis and I face a problem with the appendices.

My code is below:

```
   \documentclass[12pt]{book}

    % package to activate greek language - the sequence languages appear below is IMPORTANT!!!
    \usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
    \usepackage{varioref}
    %\usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    % package to handle graphics
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \graphicspath{{images/}}
    % package to handle multiple figures in a minipage
    \usepackage{subfigure}
    % package to extend math capabilities
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,isotope}
    \usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
    %package to activate XeTeX font manager
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

    % DOCUMENT LAYOUT
    \usepackage{geometry} 
    \geometry{a4paper, textwidth=5.5in, textheight=8.5in, headheight= 15pt, marginparsep=7pt, marginparwidth=.6in}
    %\geometry{a4paper}
    \setlength\parindent{8mm}
    \setlength\parskip{5mm}

    % FONTS
    \usepackage{xunicode}
    \usepackage{xltxtra}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text} % converts LaTeX specials (``quotes'' --- dashes etc.) to unicode
    %\setromanfont [Ligatures={Common}, BoldFont={GFS Artemisia Bold}, ItalicFont={Gentium Italic}]{Gentium}
    %\setmonofont[Scale=0.8]{Monaco} 
    \setmainfont{Times New Roman} % You can set your main font here.

    % ---- CUSTOM AMPERSAND
    \newcommand{\amper}{{\fontspec[Scale=.95]{Gentium Italic}\selectfont\itshape\&}}

    % package to handle line spacing
    \usepackage{setspace}

    % HEADINGS
    \usepackage{sectsty} 
    \usepackage[normalem]{ulem} 
    \sectionfont{\rmfamily\mdseries\upshape\Large}
    \subsectionfont{\rmfamily\bfseries\upshape\normalsize} 
    \subsubsectionfont{\rmfamily\mdseries\upshape\normalsize} 

    % PDF SETUP
    % ---- FILL IN HERE THE DOC TITLE AND AUTHOR
    \usepackage[unicode, driverfallback=dvipdfmx, bookmarks, colorlinks, breaklinks, pdftitle={Theo J. Mertzimekis - A thesis template for UoA students},pdfauthor={tmertzi}]{hyperref}  
    \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,filecolor=black,urlcolor=blue} 

    % package for fancy style headers and footers
    \usepackage{fancybox}


    % redefine bullet symbols and section style
    \renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}.}
    \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\blacktriangleright$}
    \renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\bullet$}

    \newcommand{\itemcheck}{\item[\checkmark]}
    \newcommand{\itembullet}{\item[$\bullet$]}
    \newcommand{\itemdiamond}{\item[$\diamond$]}
    \newcommand{\itemtriangleright}{\item[$\triangleright$]}
    \newcommand{\itemcirc}{\item[$\circ$]}
    \newcommand{\itemsquare}{\item[$\square$]}

    % change captions especially for greek language - if the document is in ENGLISH, they should vanish
    \addto\captionsenglish{%
      \renewcommand\prefacename{Πρόλογος}%
      \renewcommand\refname{Αναφορές}%
      \renewcommand\abstractname{Περίληψη}%
      \renewcommand\bibname{Βιβλιογραφία}%
      \renewcommand\chaptername{Κεφάλαιο}%
      \renewcommand\appendixname{Παράρτημα}%
      \renewcommand\contentsname{Περιεχόμενα}%
      \renewcommand\listfigurename{Κατάλογος Σχημάτων}%
      \renewcommand\listtablename{Κατάλογος Πινάκων}%
      \renewcommand\indexname{Ευρετήριο}%
      \renewcommand\figurename{Σχήμα}%
      \renewcommand\tablename{Πίνακας}%
      \renewcommand\partname{Μέρος}%
      \renewcommand\enclname{Συνημμένα}%
      \renewcommand\ccname{Κοινοποίηση}%
      \renewcommand\headtoname{Προς}%
      \renewcommand\pagename{Σελίδα}%
      \renewcommand\seename{βλέπε}%
      \renewcommand\alsoname{βλέπε επίσης}%
      \renewcommand\proofname{Απόδειξη}%
      \renewcommand\glossaryname{Γλωσσάρι}%
      }

    \usepackage{xgreek}

    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \usepackage[backref=true,backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark}
    \cfoot{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}}

    \usepackage{afterpage}

    \newcommand\blankpage{%
        \null
        \thispagestyle{empty}%
        %\addtocounter{page}{-1}%
        \newpage}

    %%%%%%%%% END OF PREAMBLE %%%%%%%%%%%%

    \begin{document}

    \setlanguage{greek} %% this is to activate greek hyphenation
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \chapter{Related Work}
    ...

    \begin{appendices}
        \chapter{Μοντέλο}
    \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

Does anyone know why this box is appeared next to letter A and how can I remove it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome again: Could you please edit your question? The end document is missing.

Comment: Thank you both! I have updated the question

Comment: I think the issue here is the usage of package `xgreek` and package `appendix`. Without it I do not get your box (I get an apostroph instead your box). Can you explain me what `xgreek` does for you? Why do you change the english words to be greek instead of using language `greek` as main language? Do you need english in your document or do you only use it in the bibliography?

Comment: I need to use both greek and english languages in the thesis (e.g. I will use english terms) so I need to switch between these languages, but this package was included in the university's template. When you say to use greek as main language you mean in babel? I believe that without the xgreek package I should write the command to select a language each time I need to switch between those two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed the below commands:

- `\usepackage{xgreek}`, which is causing the problem
- `\setlanguage{greek}`

The box now is removed from the appendix whithout affecting the switching between English and Greek languages.